# How to update MySql timestamp column to current timestamp on PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, timestamp, sql-update

I want to update the columns of data type `timestamp` manually through my PHP code.

Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Does it have to be the PHP timestamp instead of mySQL's `NOW()`?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use this query:

```
UPDATE `table` SET date_date=now();
```

---

Sample code can be:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET date_date=now()");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: when we talk about timestamp, we usually mean GMT. this will give date with server time zone.

Answer (score 20):

Another option:

```
UPDATE `table` SET the_col = current_timestamp
```

Looks odd, but works as expected.  If I had to guess, I'd wager this is slightly faster than calling `now()`.

Comment: Should not be fast, as according this (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) it's just a synonym for now()